# Text widget displaying in Reload but not in Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have class which will fetch the data from an API and store the result in a LIST and display the content in my text widget. When I hot reload it's displaying 'Default'. But is working fine when just reload again though I guard the text widget against the NULL.

The following is my code:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SampleState createState() => SampleState();
}

class SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  var selected = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    callAsyncFetch();
  }

  callAsyncFetch() async {      

    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2/abc.php';    
    var response = await http.get(url);    
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(jsonData);

    for (var u in jsonData) {         
      
      if (u.substring(0, 2) == 'ABC') {
        selected.add(u);
      }
    }
    for (var u in selected) {
      print(u);
    }

    print(selected.length);  // working fine
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          selected.isEmpty
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : new Text(selected[0].toString()),
        // i have tried this also but no luck       
       new Text(selectedStudentsIT.length!=0?selectedStudentsIT[0].toString():'Default Value'),

        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running flutter clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simple issue is that, in **hot reload it will not run initState again**. you can check it by printing something in initState, while in **full reload it will call initState**.

i think you want to display data when you get response from api.

i think this can be easily achieved by **calling setState** at the **end of callAsyncFetch function**, so when you get data from server then it will update ui.